# How do you then ensure you are reading the time only when you render the json in Rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, time, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem, I recently found out that Ruby can't save down a 'Time HH:MM:SS' to the DB. If you use the time type in a migration on rails as follows:

```
class CreateParkings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :parkings do |t|
      t.date :ArrivalDate
      t.time :ArrivalTime
      t.date :DepartDate
      t.time :DepartTime
      t.integer :NumberOfPax
      t.string :Title
      t.string :Initial
      t.string :Surname
      t.string :Email
      t.string :Waiver
      t.string :Remarks
      t.string :ABTANumber
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby then save the record as follows in the DB =>/ `HH:MM:SS`

But when you retrieve the data from and render it as json, then it displays with a date also of "2000-01-01T23:12:15.000Z"

As follows:

```
{
  "parking": {
    "id": 10,
    "ArrivalDate": "2018-09-19",
    "ArrivalTime": "2000-01-01T23:12:15.000Z",
    "DepartDate": "2018-09-19",
    "DepartTime": "2000-01-01T23:12:15.000Z",
    "NumberOfPax": 2018,
    "Title": "Mr Stanley",
    "Initial": "SM",
    "Surname": "Morris",
    "Email": "stanley.morris@someemail.com",
    "Waiver": "No Waiver",
    "Remarks": "I will be parking late in the evening. ",
    "ABTANumber": "HJKJKHDS123",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "admin",
      "email": "admin@admin.com",
      "admin": true,
      "member": true
    }
  }
}
```

How do I ensure that the time only is rendered in the json. I've read that I will need to use `{Attribute}.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`. But I'm not sure how to loop through the the parkings collection. And convert each of the Attributes to this format `HH:MM:SS`

If you have any ideas I would be grateful.

Comment: Why do you need to loop through the parkings collection and convert the values? If it's about rendering the correct format, then you can have a method in the `Parking` model to format the time.
Then you can use this method when you render the JSON response.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. But I'll investigate this option.

Comment: how do you create the json response? just rendering the object with `.to_json`? if the default behavior does not work for you you can always render the json whatever you want redefining `as_json` method or using something like JBuilder.

Comment: I use rails 5.2.1 (API) so I render my json like this:
render json: @parkings

Comment: @Hesham Youssef - If you care to elaborate on how I can use a def in my model to achieve this, that would be very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a method in the `Parking` model like:

```
def formatted_arrival_time
  arrival_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end
```

And then in the serializer, I would use `formatted_arrival_time` instead of `arrival_time`

Comment: I get an error but I wonder if its because my attributes are actually in camelcase. 
NameError: uninitialized constant Parking::ArrivalTime

Comment: Added self and it works a charm, thanks 

def formatted_arrival_time
    self.ArrivalTime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 end